# How do I remove one arrays contents from another arrays elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays as codely illustrated below:

```
let arrayOne = [1669683600000, 1669770000000, 1669698000000, 1669755600000];
let arrayTwo = [1669683600000, 1669770000000];
```

I would like to remove the contents of `arrayTwo` from `arrayOne`.
I thought the code below would work:

```
let results = arrayOne.filter((item)=> item !== arrayTwo);
console.log('results: ' ,results );
```

The code above yeilds:

```
results: [1669683600000, 1669770000000, 1669698000000, 1669755600000]
```

The desired results are:

```
results: [1669698000000, 1669755600000]
```

How do I achieve my desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` but only include the item if it is not(`!`) in(`includes`) `arrayTwo`

```js
let arrayOne = [1669683600000, 1669770000000, 1669698000000, 1669755600000];
let arrayTwo = [1669683600000, 1669770000000];

console.log(arrayOne.filter((item)=>!arrayTwo.includes(item)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **filter**

```
arrayOne = arrayOne.filter(function(val) {
  return arrayTwo.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```